# check no firewall between two pc on diff network by port 8443

Tags: firewall

I have WIN XP

I need to Check: there is not firewall between desktop (my PC IP = 23.4.66.129) 
to other PC (IP 23.4.66.4)   port 8443

how to check that? by telnet from cmd Window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you running?

- Run a packet analyzer on the destination PC (something like `tcpdump` on Linux or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on both Linux and Windows). While you listen on the interface that has 23.4.66.4 bound, do a `telnet 23.4.66.4 8443` on the source PC. If you see a connection attempt there's no filtering.
- Listen on that port for connections with any daemon or, better yet, `netcat`. `nc -l 8443` listens for connections on that port. Then connect from the source PC using `nc 23.4.66.4 8443` or `telnet 23.4.66.4 8443`. If you are able to connect there's no filtering.

Edit: I see you clarified that you're using Windows. There should be a more Windows-friendly way of doing this, but you can still use either Wireshark or the [Windows port of netcat](http://joncraton.org/files/nc111nt.zip).

Comment: Not as a criticism of this answer, but as a warning: some antivirus and firewalls may raise alarm bells on **nc** (netcat) or **nmap**. It's not bad to let your and remote network administrators know that you are going to do.